# Updating a form's select option using Drupal 7 Form API

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Each one of the manufacturer logos listed below the form should (on click) change the option value to whatever the user clicks. For example: if the user clicks the vulcan image, the form needs to be updated with the VULCAN select option prior to the form submission. The form options are being populated with the DB query I have listed in the code. That works fine, so no problems there.

The manufacturer images are populated by the Views module. I have included a picture of those settings as well for clarity's sake.

So my question is: What is a good way to give those manufacturer images the functionality to change the selected option? My php is very noob, but I'm guessing it has something to do with changing the #default_value using the Form API?

Any help would be appreciated!!

[image: View settings for Manufacturer Logos]

[image: This is a preview of the block I am working with.]

```
function part_finder_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $options = part_finder_form_get_manufacturer_list();
  $form['manufacturer'] = array(
   '#prefix' => '<span class="right_arrow"></span>',
   '#type' => 'select',
   '#required' => TRUE,
   '#empty_option' => t('Start by selecting a manufacturer...'),
   '#options' => $options,

);
$form['submit'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => 'Go',
);
return $form;
}

function part_finder_form_get_manufacturer_list() {
  $options = array();
  $results = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE type = :type", array(':type' => 'rep_manufacturers'));
  foreach ($results as $option) {
  $options[$option->nid] = $option->title;
}

return $options;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using jQuery.

Here is a sample code. (in this code I'm assuming that the image title stores the value you need to pass to your select)

```
var images = jQuery('#image_wrapper img');
var select = jQuery('#manufacturer');
images.click(function()
{
select.val(jQuery(this).attr('title'));
});
```

You can add this code to a separate javascript file, and then add it to the form using $form['#attached']

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array('PATH_TO_JS_FILE');
```

Hope this works for you

Muhammad.